# how should we approach with this error "list indices must be integers, not unicode"

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to remove all the new lines,tabs and print only the text from the list variable named `tables`
These tables are obtained by scraping the WHO website [page](https://www.who.int/countries/en/)

```py
In [43]: tables[0]=tables[0].text.strip().replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
In [44]: tables[0]
Out[44]: u'A    Afghanistan    Albania    Algeria    Andorra    Angola    Antigua and Barbuda    Argentina    Armenia    Australia    Austria    Azerbaijan'
```

It was fine until here and then when I tried to iterate over the tables the following happened.

```py
In [45]: for i in tables:
    ...:     tables[i] =  tables[i].text.strip().replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
    ...:     print(tables[i])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-7630bb467dfd> in <module>()
      1 for i in tables:
----> 2     tables[i] =  tables[i].text.strip().replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
      3     print(tables[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

This was my other failed attempt

```py
In [47]: for i in range(len(tables)):
    ...:     tables[i] =  tables[i].text.strip().replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
    ...:     print(tables[i])
    ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-84306fc0c373> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(len(tables)):
----> 2     tables[i] =  tables[i].text.strip().replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
      3     print(tables[i])
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Having been a beautifulsoup noob I request for your help folks!

Comment: Try `for i in range(len(tables)):`

Comment: I am getting this error 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my  solution

```py
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                             
In [2]: import requests                                                                   
In [3]: url = 'https://www.who.int/countries/en/'                                                                           
In [4]: content = requests.get(url).content                                                                        
In [5]: soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html5lib')                                                                   
In [6]: divs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'largebox'})                                                     
In [7]: countries = []                                                                                             
In [8]: for div in divs: 
   ...:     li = div.findAll('li') 
   ...:     for l in li: 
   ...:         print(l.a.text)
```

This has a rigorous solution but works. I've identified that each alphabet has a `div` for itself with `class = largebox` and each country is a `html` `li` item wrapped inside an anchor (`a`) tag. So iterating through all of the divs and list items gave me the following result.

```py
Afghanistan 
Albania 
Algeria 
Andorra 
Angola 
Antigua and Barbuda 
Argentina 
Armenia 
Australia 
Austria 
Azerbaijan 
Bahamas 
Bahrain 
Bangladesh 
Barbados 
Belarus 
Belgium 
Belize 
Benin 
Bhutan 
Bolivia (Plurinational State of) 
Bosnia and Herzegovina 
Botswana 
Brazil 
Brunei Darussalam 
Bulgaria 
Burkina Faso 
Burundi 
Cabo Verde 
Cambodia 
Cameroon 
Canada 
Central African Republic 
Chad 
Chile 
China 
Colombia 
Comoros 
Congo 
Cook Islands 
Costa Rica 
Côte d'Ivoire 
Croatia 
Cuba 
Cyprus 
Czechia 
Democratic People's Republic of Korea 
Democratic Republic of the Congo 
Denmark 
Djibouti 
Dominica 
Dominican Republic 
Ecuador 
Egypt 
El Salvador 
Equatorial Guinea 
Eritrea 
Estonia 
Eswatini 
Ethiopia 
Fiji 
Finland 
France 
Gabon 
Gambia 
Georgia 
Germany 
Ghana 
Greece 
Grenada 
Guatemala 
Guinea 
Guinea-Bissau 
Guyana 
Haiti 
Honduras 
Hungary 
Iceland 
India 
Indonesia 
Iran (Islamic Republic of) 
Iraq 
Ireland 
Israel 
Italy 
Jamaica 
Japan 
Jordan 
Kazakhstan 
Kenya 
Kiribati 
Kuwait 
Kyrgyzstan 
Lao People's Democratic Republic 
Latvia 
Lebanon 
Lesotho 
Liberia 
Libya 
Lithuania 
Luxembourg 
Madagascar 
Malawi 
Malaysia 
Maldives 
Mali 
Malta 
Marshall Islands 
Mauritania 
Mauritius 
Mexico 
Micronesia (Federated States of) 
Monaco 
Mongolia 
Montenegro 
Morocco 
Mozambique 
Myanmar 
Namibia 
Nauru 
Nepal 
Netherlands 
New Zealand 
Nicaragua 
Niger 
Nigeria 
Niue 
North Macedonia 
Norway 
Oman 
Pakistan 
Palau 
Panama 
Papua New Guinea 
Paraguay 
Peru 
Philippines 
Poland 
Portugal 
Qatar 
Republic of Korea 
Republic of Moldova 
Romania 
Russian Federation 
Rwanda 
Saint Kitts and Nevis 
Saint Lucia 
Saint Vincent and the Grenadines 
Samoa 
San Marino 
Sao Tome and Principe 
Saudi Arabia 
Senegal 
Serbia  
Seychelles 
Sierra Leone 
Singapore 
Slovakia 
Slovenia 
Solomon Islands 
Somalia 
South Africa 
South Sudan 
Spain 
Sri Lanka 
Sudan 
Suriname 
Sweden 
Switzerland 
Syrian Arab Republic 
Tajikistan 
Thailand 
Timor-Leste 
Togo 
Tonga 
Trinidad and Tobago 
Tunisia 
Turkey 
Turkmenistan 
Tuvalu 
Uganda 
Ukraine 
United Arab Emirates 
United Kingdom 
United Republic of Tanzania 
United States of America 
Uruguay 
Uzbekistan 
Vanuatu 
Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of) 
Viet Nam 
Yemen 
Zambia 
Zimbabwe
```

**UPDATE**
find an better version [here](https://gist.github.com/sakethramanujam/b156c13e34e513c65db542fc5f8f0221)

Answer (score 0):

The last code block you show should work. The error you get suggests that your `tables` object (which I'm guessing is a list?) contains data of inconsistent types. Some entries are presumably objects with a `text` attribute, but at least one is a Unicode string. Perhaps this is because you manually modified `tables[0]` using the code in the first code block? If that's the case, reconstructing the data (e.g. by re-scraping, or reprocessing the data from some earlier intermediate result) should fix the error. Or if only index `0` is modified already and you don't mind a one-off fix, just change your range to start at index `1` (`for i in range(1, len(tables))`).

The middle code block doesn't work because you're iterating over the items in the list, but trying to use them as indexes. You could perhaps use `enumerate` to get an index as you go, and use the index for the in-place assignment:

```
for i, value in enumerate(tables):
    tables[i] = some_processing(value) # details of the processing omitted for brevity
```

Another approach that is often better is to create a new list with the processed values, rather than trying to modify the original list in place. This also avoids causing issues like the first one I mentioned above, since you'll be leaving the original list unchanged, so you can reprocess it again if you find you didn't do it right the first time, when creating a new list. List comprehensions are often a good way to build a new list from an existing one. I'd use:

```
processed_tables = [process(value) for value in tables]
```

Or, if you don't need to keep the processed values around at all, only print them out, you could use a simple loop and a local variable:

```
for value in tables:
    processed_value = process(value)
    print(processed_value)
```

You could even skip the local variable assignment do everything in one line, with a loop body like `print(process(value))`.